# Mapped OneDrive on a Terminal Server

Tags: onedrive, sharepoint

1st post, be gentle :)

I am currently working in a Hosted Desktop Solution business and more and more clients are starting to utilise OneDrive/Sharepoint combos.

This is great however immediately we come up against some issues, namely:

1. OneDrive Mapped Drives are only as big as the Drive they are on.  So If the C Drive has 100GB free on it and we install OneDrive there in a 2019 TS with FOD the size of the OD is 100GB - it cant utilise the 1TB that the OD account has. The files need to be uploaded to the OD account via the web 1st then the FOD can come into play. This seems like normal practice to me and i doubt there is a way around it, is there?
2. In a TS scenario we are finding that the OD installation needs to be installed either under the Admin account or a user account (which then has to remain logged in permanently - NOT GOOD) then the OD mapped as a shared drive for all users to see.  Is there another way around this?
3. The above scenario gets even worse if we are mapping to a SharePoint location as mapping the drive linked to the site is problematic with deep linking/long names etc - any ideas on best practice for this?
4. Having say 10 users logging into a TS then ALL having SharePoint shared is the reason we map the SharePoint drives so they dont need OD updating SP constantly PER USER HOWEVER more and more we are seeing clients wanting their employees to have "personal business OD" per user which is truly a nightmare on a TS, we end up with a scenario where OD is updating the Business wide shared SharePoint AND the individual users OD constantly throughout the day, it grinds even the most lushly resource rich 2019 TS to a halt rapidly.  Again any suggestions for combating this would be appreciated.

I have read recently that MS has a Sync App Per Machine for OD but never tested it (http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/per-machine-installation) any tried this with any success in this type of scenario?

Anyway i know thats a lot of questions and hope its pretty clear and will be most grateful and appreciative of any feedback or suggestions.

Regards,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

The 4 points listed shows you this is indeed not the way you would want to go.

Keep in mind that the optimal solution is to not use OneDrive at all, but it is still possible.

What you would want to do is use the fileserver instead and let the OneDrive sync to the large partition. You can then create a fileshare for the folder and allow everyone on the TS to access the OneDrive files that way.

True, the admin user would still need to be logged in on the fileserver, but that is very doable. You should definitely remove OneDrive from the TS. It is a resource hog especially with multiple users and the more users share files, the more duplicate files you get on the TS because all users download the same files.

If you were to migrate all data from OneDrive to the fileserver, you can then use a VPN solution to allow everyone access the data remotely.

Comment: HI There, thanks for the reply.
Yeah we try to get clients to not use OD but they insist as its part of their O365.
We cant tell them to use a file server as its additional cost and they dont like that.
We try not to allow to many VPNs apart from printing.

Im looking to get them to a Sharepoint solution and force them to not use OD but it aint working so far.